# How to Enable/Disable Multiple Buttons Simultaneously Without Writing Code For Each Individual Button?

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am currently coding a simple hangman game that has a button for each letter that the player can input as their guess. When the game ends I want all the Letter Buttons (a, b, c, d, etc.) to be disabled so the user cannot click on them until they press the start game button and a new word is generated. I was wondering if it's possible to disable all the letter buttons without writing this for each button:
`button1.enabled = False button2.enabled = False button3.enabled = False...`

I was wondering if I could instead only write a few lines in comparison to 26 lines of code to achieve this.

I have tried this but it is very inefficient and I was wondering if there is a different option?
`button1.enabled = False button2.enabled = False button3.enabled = False...`

The circled buttons are the ones I want to disable: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GUOO.png)

Thank you in advance,
Georgie

Comment: You could put the buttons in a panel (or other container) then disable the panel.  Or you could loop over the Forms.Controls collection and disable the required controls as you see fit.  That aside though, wouldn't think 26 lines of code for enabling/disabling buttons on demand is overly inefficient as it gives you total control, probably took you longer to write this question then to just do it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would I go about putting the buttons in a panel or other container? Sorry for the hassle. You're right in that it took longer but I think disabling the buttons through another way other than the 26 lines of code can help me learn better and use the knowledge in the future as I am still very new to coding.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a winforms app I admit.  Just drag a panel from the toolbox same as you did with the original buttons, then just move them inside the panel.  Just be aware, you may have to re-wire any event handlers for those buttons after moving them

Comment: If you move the `Buttons` into a `Panel` as suggested above, be sure to drag and drop them, rather than cut and paste. If you do the former then all `Handles` clauses on event handlers will remain intact. If you do the latter, you are effectively deleting them temporarily so all associated `Handles` clauses will be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Hursey said in comment, create a panel and move all involved buttons in it with mouse.

then you can loop thru children controls :

```
For Each CtrlButton As Control In Panel1.Controls
    If TypeOf CtrlButton Is Button Then 'only buttons
        CtrlButton.Enabled = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the help. It all worked perfectly. Thank you for all the suggestions and help!